# Can VBA macros from Powerpoint 2003 be used in Powerpoint 2010?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Apologies in advance for asking about an evil Microsoft product!

Anyway, I have a variety of macros and add-ons for Powerpoint 2003 that have convenient buttons, keyboard shortcuts, and objects that auto-format, etc. The only problem is that there is a fairly large amount of code that isn't perfectly commented and that I didn't write.

I've tried without success to migrate it to Powerpoint 2010, but I'm not sure if it's due to the fact that I may not have imported them correctly or whether there are fundamental differences or incompatabilities in the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: By and large code that worked in previous versions should still work, unless you're moving to Office 2010/64-bit.  Masters and layouts and such are handled quite differently in 2007/2010 vs older versions, so most likely anything that manipulates them would need to be modified/rewritten.  It order to take it further, it might be a good idea if you can describe what specifically isn't working and how you're trying to migrate the code.  "Migrating" shouldn't involve much more than opening the old source PPT and saving as PPTM

Answer (score 0):

Code should work.  Make sure you have the proper settings in Trust Center.